# how can I create Bottom in flutter like the image in quetsion?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am using Flutter to develop an app and I'm going to create an introduction page but I can't create the button like this, what I'm gonna do?
just the next button...

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can draw any shapes in flutter as widget with CustomPaint
take a look at this link:

https://blog.logrocket.com/drawing-shapes-in-flutter-with-custompaint-and-shape-maker/